# Keep Receiving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class '...' does not have the property '...'

Tags: jsp, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I am doing a project which searches a specific member from my database searching for his **memberId** and then show selected information, but **I'm having trouble with my Java Class Setter**(not really sure if it was really the problem) because I keep on receiving error message from the catch(Exception ex)

**javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'Project.Members' does not have the property 'FirstName'.**

Can you help me figure out what was wrong with my code?

**This is my servlet code:**

```
public class SearchAMember extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "SELECT memberId, FirstName FROM members WHERE memberId = ?";
    try {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet SelectDemo</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        try {
            Class.forName(Connect.DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connect.CONNECTION_STRING,
                    Connect.USERNAME, Connect.PASSWORD);

            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            int findId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            stmt.setInt(1, findId);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            Members std;
            if (rs.next()) {
                std = new Members();
                std.setMemberId(rs.getInt("memberId"));
                std.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                request.setAttribute("Members", std);
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayAllMembers.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                out.println("No record found...");
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            out.println("Driver not found...");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            out.println("Failed connection or query...." + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.println("Error.... " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
    } finally {
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}

/*<--HttpServlet Method was here-->*/
}
```

}

and my **Member.java** class for my getter and setter:

public class Members {

```
private int memberId;
private String Username;
private String Password;
private String FirstName;
private String MiddleName;
private String LastName;
private String Address;
private String Email;
private int CurrPoints;

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public int getCurrPoints() {
    return CurrPoints;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return FirstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return LastName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return MiddleName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}

public int getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}

public void setAddress(String Address) {
    this.Address = Address;
}

public void setCurrPoints(int CurrPoints) {
    this.CurrPoints = CurrPoints;
}

public void setEmail(String Email) {
    this.Email = Email;
}

public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
}

public void setLastName(String LastName) {
    this.LastName = LastName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String MiddleName) {
    this.MiddleName = MiddleName;
}

public void setPassword(String Password) {
    this.Password = Password;
}

public void setUsername(String Username) {
    this.Username = Username;
}

public void setMemberId(int memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}
```

}

also this is my **Jsp**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Members Information</h1>
    Id: ${Members.memberId}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Name: ${Members.FirstName}<br/>
</body>
```

Does the problem was at my **Members.java** class? I am really clueless what was wrong with it... please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should respect the Java naming conventions. Variables always start with a lowercase letter. Properties also start with a lowercase letter. And since the Members class represents one member, you should also call it Member, not Members.

```
request.setAttribute("member", std);

public class Member {
    private String firstName;
    // ...
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }
}

Id: ${member.memberId}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Name: ${member.firstName}<br/>
```

Comment: thank you very much sir JB Nizet... i forgot about java do's and dont's now i've learn my lesson... thanks again sir :)